# Can I refreeze gravlax made from previously frozen salmon

Tags: freezing, fish, salmon

Can I refreeze gravlax made from previously frozen salmon?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's even recommended to use salmon that has been frozen for at least 24 hours to make gravadlax as a precaution against parasites, since the salmon isn't cooked. (Of course I'm assuming that you want *some* right away!)

Prepared gravadlax freezes very well. As Jenna says, wrap it individually in cling wrap, and freeze for up to a couple of months for best quality. Refrigerate it for a few hours to thaw before serving.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will freeze fine, just make sure you wrap each slice or piece individually.

Comment: I made the mistake of not wrapping each slice individually once. It was still delicious, but more like shredded gravlax than slices.